# mysql command not found in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, macos

On my mac, if I type mysql --version in bash, the bash shows that command not found.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/merle/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql\@5.5/bin:/Users/merle/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-4.0.4/bin:/Applications/PostgreSQL\ 10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

$ /usr/local/opt/mysql\@5.5/bin/mysql --version
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ mysql --version
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I add the mysql bin directory to my PATH variable in my .bashrc.
I don't know what is going on.

Comment: What is the output of `which mysql`?

Comment: There is no output.

Comment: Maybe try to log out and log in?

Comment: Tried, didn't work,

Comment: How did you install mysql?

Comment: Try to remove the backslash (\\) from the PATH (just before `@5.5`)

Comment: @tink I use brew install mysql@5.5

Comment: @AnDrOiD It works...

Comment: @Merle Awesome. Just make sure to mark my answer so it'll be easier for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the backslash (\) in the PATH env:

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql\@5.5/bin
```

After removing it:

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/bin
```

Comment: If I am in /usr/local/opt/, and I type cd my+Tab, it becomes cd mysql\@5.5. Why would this happen?

Comment: I guess it depends on the context. From what we see, when using a `@` in bash you'd need to escape it (`\@`); when using it in an environment variable you don't.

Comment: @Merle, a \ would also appear in a folder name with spaces. The blackslash is needed on the command line to let Bash know it's one contiguous variable, but in the bashrc, it is not required because it knows to go until the delimiter `:`

Comment: @jeremysprofile but this folder mysql@5.5 doesn't have spaces.

Comment: It depends on how it was assigned in `.bashrc`: if it's `PATH="/mysql\@5.5/bin"`, the backslash will be preserved; if it's `PATH=/mysql\@5.5/bin`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW, there's a similar problem with `/Applications/PostgreSQL\ 10/bin` in that `PATH`. And the solution is the same: use a backslash or quotes (but not both) *when defining the `PATH` value*, so that the quotes or backslash get parsed & removed before it's actually assigned to the variable.

Comment: @Merle : I guess the reason that tab-expanding produced \@ is that if _extglob_ is enabled, @ is a special character in a glob pattern and hence needs to be escaped when typing on the command line. For instance, if you have a file named (literally) `x*`, tab-expansion would result into `x\*`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mysql to your env. Based on what are you using (standard bash or zsh or other), you need to open the configuration file such as

`~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and add there the following

```sh
export PATH = "${PATH}/etc/local/mysql/bin"
```

Do not forget to do to apply the changes

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```